# why sequelize returning field names in lowercase

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

I've defined my model with camelCase field names. however when I run `findOne`, or `findAll`, the data returned by the query is always in lowercase not matching the model. I tried checking the query by enabling logging, query seems fine it is still selecting field names as is in the model(camelcase). can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Note: I'm using PostgreSQL

Here's my model:

```
const reportSchema = {
  reportId: {
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false
  },
  reportName: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  reportCategory: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  }
```

Here's my connection configuration:

```
new Sequelize(databaseConfig.dbName, databaseConfig.dbUsername, databaseConfig.dbPassword, {
  host: databaseConfig.dbHost,
  port: databaseConfig.dbPort,
  dialect: 'postgres',
  quoteIdentifiers: false,
  query: {
    raw: true
  }
  // logging: false
});
```

Note: I think the problem might be with `quoteIdentifier` option in connection configuration. but without that setting to false, I couldn't be able to access the table That I've created in PascalCase. If I set it to true, it surrounding field names with double quotes in the query which is not valid in Postgres for camelcase I guess

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: thanks for your quick response. what code you wanna see? model definition or connection configuration or findOne query?

Comment: Yes, the model and any overrides to the connection setup config. Are your table column names also lower-case? Include your SQL table definition as well.

Comment: updated. can you please have a look

Comment: By default Postgres folds all identifier names to lower case (as opposed to the SQL Standard which specifies upper case).  This effectively makes the name usage case incentive; as "myData", "MyData", "MYDATA" all fold in the same value "mydata". You can force Postgres to keep the specified case by putting it within double quotes ("). However, you must then **always use double quotes** as unquoted values do not match the quoted ones:  MyData is not the same as "MyData".